# How can I use AND function only for specific text in a column with unknown number of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-conditions

I try to create a formula in another sheet that verify for the first sheet if all the following conditions are true: In Column A ="User 1", column C starts with "01" and for Column B are more conditions: If Column B="Urlaub" returns "CM", if Column B="Krankenstand", returns "CO", if Column B="Sonstige" returns "CP" and ignore the rest.

The problem is I can't use AND function because in Column A are more users (User2, User3 etc.) and in Column B are more texts, I'm looking for a function to work only for User1 and the 3 conditions for Column B and ignore the rest.

I tried the following formula :

```
=IF(AND('Sheet1'!A:A="User1",LEFT('Sheet1'!C:C,2)="01",'Sheet1'!B:B="Urlaub"),"CM",
IF(AND('Sheet1'!A:A="User1",LEFT('Sheet1'!C:C,2)="01",'Sheet1'!B2="Krankenstand"),"CO","CP"))
```

I attach an image with the excel table I'm working on and the results I'm looking for.

[excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyEdp.png)
[the results I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiRw8.png)

Comment: Shouldn't you only have one match for your example data since there's only one cell in the C-column that starts with "01"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I reuploaded a new image with the table.

Comment: Please provide markdown sample data, not screenshots. Also, the zero's in the desired result, is that a requirement?

Comment: Yes, the zero it's a must.